# Python- How do I sort a list that the script is building to replicate another word?

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting

I'm trying to implement a hangman game. I want part of the function to check if a letter is correct or incorrect. After a letter is found to be correct it will place the letter in a "used letters" list and a "correct letters list" The correct letters list will be built as the game goes on. I'd like it to sort the list to match the hidden word as the game is going.

For instance let's use the word "hardware"
If someone guessed "e, a, and h" it would come out like

```
correct = ["e", "a", "h"]
```

I would like it to sort the list so it would go

```
correct = ["h", "a", "e"]
```

then

`correct = ["h", "a", "r", "a", "e"]` after r has been guessed.

I also need to know if it would also see that "a" is in there twice and place it twice.

---

My code that doesn't allow you to win but you can lose. It's a work in progress.
I also can't get the letters left counter to work. I've made the code print the list to check if it was adding the letters. it is. So I don't know what's up there.

```
def hangman():
    correct = []
    guessed = []
    guess = ""
    words = ["source", "alpha", "patch", "system"]
    sWord = random.choice(words)
    wLen = len(sWord)
    cLen = len(correct)
    remaining = int(wLen - cLen)
    print "Welcome to hangman.\n"
    print "You've got 3 tries or the guy dies."
    turns = 3   

    while turns > 0: 
        guess = str(raw_input("Take a guess. >"))

        if guess in sWord:          
            correct.append(guess)
            guessed.append(guess)   
            print "Great!, %d letters left." % remaining        
        else:
            print "Incorrect, this poor guy's life is in your hands."
            guessed.append(guess)
            turns -= 1
            print "You have %d turns left." % turns

    if turns == 0:
        print "HE'S DEAD AND IT'S ALL YOUR FAULT! ARE YOU HAPPY?"
        print "YOU LOST ON PURPOSE, DIDN'T YOU?!"

hangman()
```

Comment: Where is your code? Post a short self contained example.

Comment: @Cinch It's in there now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the desired behavior because:

> `correct = ["h", "a", "r", "a", "e"]` after `r` has been guessed.

This is strange because `a` has only been guessed once, but shows up for each time it appears in `hardware`. Should `r` should also appear twice? If that is the correct behavior, then a very simple list comprehension can be used:

```
def result(guesses, key):
  print [c for c in key if c in guesses]

In [560]: result('eah', 'hardware')
['h', 'a', 'a', 'e']

In [561]: result('eahr', 'hardware')
['h', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'e']
```

Iterate the letters in key and include them if the letter has been used as a "guess".

You can also have it insert a place holder for unfound characters fairly easily by using:

```
def result(guesses, key):
  print [c if c in guesses else '_' for c in key]
  print ' '.join([c if c in guesses else '_' for c in key])

In [567]: result('eah', 'hardware')
['h', 'a', '_', '_', '_', 'a', '_', 'e']
h a _ _ _ a _ e

In [568]: result('eahr', 'hardware')
['h', 'a', 'r', '_', '_', 'a', 'r', 'e']
h a r _ _ a r e

In [569]: result('eahrzw12', 'hardware')
['h', 'a', 'r', '_', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e']
h a r _ w a r e
```

Comment: You're right about the R being single and there being 2 A's, I don't have as good of an attention to detail as a programmer should. I am a noob, though. I'm assuming you're assuming I know how to create a key, I don't. Unless that's how you make one then that is fine. Thanks for your help, I wish I could try it out. Sadly I'm at work looking at this on my phone during lunch.

Comment: The 'key' is just a string. In your case, 'sWord'.